# CustomCell in XCode not displaying value

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I created a custom cell in table view that has a search bar. Text entered by users will be used to search a SQLite db and results displayed in table view. The problem I have now is that the search result is not displayed in the table view if I use custom cell but works when I use the default cell. For e.g., in code below, if I use [cell setText:currentSubLocality]; it will display the result but it will not display result if I use cell.lblG.text = currentLocation;. Please help, been struggling with it for 2 days. Thanks

```
#import "CustomViewController.h"
#import "FMDBDataAccess.h"
#import "locationCode.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
@interface CustomViewController ()

@end

@implementation CustomViewController{
    NSMutableArray *searchResults;}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [searchResults count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"vvv"];

    if (cell==nil){
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"vvv"];

    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        locationCode *code = [[locationCode alloc] init];
        code= [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *currentLocation = code.location;
        NSString *currentSubLocality = code.subLocality

        //[cell setText:currentSubLocality];
        cell.lblG.text = currentLocation;
        cell.lblL.text = currentSubLocality;
    }


    return cell;

}


- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSString *databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"spr" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];

    [database open];
    searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil count:0];

    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Locations where locationCode like '%@%%'", searchText];

    FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:query];

    while([results next]) {

        locationCode *code = [[locationCode alloc] init];
        code.code = [results stringForColumn:@"locationcode"];
        code.subLocality= [results stringForColumn:@"sublocality"];
        code.longitude= [results stringForColumn:@"longitude"];
        code.latitude= [results stringForColumn:@"latitude"];

        [searchResults addObject:code];
    }

    [database close];

}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: I think you need post your customcell source code

Answer (score 0):

Try This it will work. paste the below code in cellforrowatindexpath method and don't forget to set your TableViewCell "Identifier" in your Attribute inspector

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by adding the tableview as an outlet. Then change the following line

```
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"vvv"];
```

to

```
CustomCell *cell = [customTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"vvv"];
```